# How do I create a point buffer?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.1

I have a collection of points. The goal is to create a buffer around each point. The radius maybe different for each point and is based on a series of calculations. Some wells might have 10+ calculations that must be considered while others may have only one or two.

Given a point, a radius determined from my calcs, and an output feature class, how do I create a buffer around a point?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [buffer tool](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//000800000019000000) allows you to specify an attribute to buffer each feature by.  If you were to perform your calculations first and then populate a BUFFER attribute, you could easily buffer the points based on different criteria.